# vue-gtag: `gtag.js couldn't be loaded`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-analytics, analytics, gtag.js

I am new to javascript frameworks in general and trying to learn vue. I am trying to use google analytics for data collection on my site, so I'm using [vue-gtag](https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/). I followed a couple of youtube tutorials and reached here:

package.json

```
    ...
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@braid/vue-formulate": "^2.4.3",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "browser-image-compression": "^1.0.12",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-gtag": "^1.9.1",
    "vue-navigation-bar": "^4.0.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuejs-datatable": "^2.0.0-alpha.7",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    ...
```

main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

// @ts-ignore
import VueNavigationBar from "vue-navigation-bar";
import { VuejsDatatableFactory} from 'vuejs-datatable'
import VueGtag from "vue-gtag";

import "./helpers/vue-navigation-bar.css";

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $formulate: {
      handle: (err: typeof Error, formName: string, skip?: boolean) => void | typeof Error;
      reset: <V>(formName: string, initialValue?: V) => void;
      resetValidation: (formName: string) => void;
      setValues: <V>(formName: string, values: V) => void;
    };
  }
}

Vue.config.productionTip = true;
Vue.component("vue-navigation-bar", VueNavigationBar);
Vue.use(VuejsDatatableFactory);
Vue.use(VueGtag, {
  config: { id: "my id thingy" }
});

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

When I run this on localhost, I was expecting google analytics to show one Realtime user (according to a youtube video I saw), which it did not. This is the error in my browser's console:

```
[vue-gtag] Ops! Something happened and gtag.js couldn't be loaded vue-gtag.esm.js:105:11
    warn webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-gtag/dist/vue-gtag.esm.js:105
    _bootstrap webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-gtag/dist/vue-gtag.esm.js:503
    (Async: promise callback)
    _bootstrap webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-gtag/dist/vue-gtag.esm.js:502
    install webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue-gtag/dist/vue-gtag.esm.js:561
    use VueJS
    <anonymous> webpack-internal:///./src/main.ts:37
    ts http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:1910
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:854
    fn http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:151
    1 http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:2055
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:854
    checkDeferredModules http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:46
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:994
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:997
```

Apart from the `Ops!`, I would appreciate if someone could pointout where I went wrong.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try add params section in your usage: `Vue.use(VueGtag, {
  config: { 
    id: "...",
    params: {
      send_page_view: false
    }
  }
});`

Comment: hey, @MaksimTikhonov, I tried putting `params` in, unfortunately, no change in console's error.

Comment: checki this link for answer. Propably it is here https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag/issues/54

Comment: checked that before, I am using a google analytics ID `UA-*********-*`.

Comment: okay, so the error goes away after I move to an incognito window. So I guess this was my ad-blocker in the way. But Google analytics still doesn't show a user in realtime.